# Couldn't captcha be user-language-friendly?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, captcha

Hey, Captcha sometimes appears to user and it can be very difficult to guess.

Some letters are very hard to read, so I sometimes can't recognize them. But when in captcha is word I know I can guess it easier. Sometimes I have to change captcha many times to find some word I know. Many of them are difficult and not IT technical.

Couldn't the capcha be more binded with user language? F.g. in German or Russian? Stackoverflow wouldn't be then so closed for people that speak no very good English, only the technical one. And it does not make them technical weaker.

Comment: +1 for bringing it up, but I agree with CanSpice and Pekka's answers.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on meta.recaptcha.com?  SO doesn't control how reCAPTCHA is implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow is an English-language website, so it makes sense that the "words" in the captcha be English. That said, more often than not the words don't appear to be proper English anyhow. Just type the letters you see and don't worry about what language it's in.

As for the letters being hard to read, that's kind of the point of a captcha.

Comment: Well, the point of a captcha is to be hard to read *for robots*. There have been complaints about extremely complex captchas in the past few weeks.

Comment: @Pekka: True. Maybe they're getting more complex because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448963/has-recaptcha-been-cracked-hacked-ocrd-defeated-broken (mind you, that's two years old, but still, technology advances)

Comment: @pekka - my first language is english and I have a fairly decent vocabulary, but I've had to hit that captcha refresh button 6 or 7 times recently because the letters are so badly distorted. It's terrifically annoying at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good idea, but would be the job of [Recaptcha](http://www.recaptcha.com), not Stack Overflow.

They provide Captcha services to many, many sites - they would be the ones one would have to approach with the suggestion.

Comment: OCR the original image, translate, re-create, WIN!

Comment: But it is stack overflow who uses it

Comment: @volkerjaan but Stack Overflow can't change the way Recaptcha works

Comment: But they are not forced to use this particular captcha?

Comment: @volker no, but they are unlikely to switch it for this reason